# Route catching an empty error (User.findOne)

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I'm pretty sure this should be a simple thing to fix but I have no idea why its happening, I'm using nodejs and mongodb here.

This is the route I'm calling and when I do that it simply returns 404 with an empty object.
I'm sure this is not because it cant find the user with the email adress because userFound will be null in that case. But I couldn't find why its directly catching an empty error or something?

```
router.post("/notify", function (req, res) {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then((userFound) => {
      const notification = {
        type: req.body.type,
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
      };
      notification.destination = userFound;
      Notification.save(function (err, notification) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send();
        } else {
          res.send(notification);
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return res.status(404).json(error);
    });
});
```

I'm sorry I really feel stupid asking this.. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried logging the error in the catch block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add next in the parameters of your callback function :

```js
router.post("/notify", function (req, res, next) {
  User.findOne(...)
    .catch((error) => next(error));
});
```

Comment: I tried your first statement with the message but its the same  it returns this `{
    "message": {}
}`

Comment: and with the next I'm getting this error now 

`TypeError: Notification.save is not a function`

Comment: Well, at least you can start troubleshoot now, right?

Comment: indeed and i actually now what's the issue! Thanks! I'll put your ansswer as the correct one since you helped solve this!

Comment: Thanks Abderrahmen.

Answer (score 0):

Well first thanks to all of your help guys it turns out that I really did something very stupid, I was actually calling `Notification.save()` instead of the const name which is `notification.save()` so that's why i was getting the `Notification.save is not a function` error